# HTML5 show download button in firefox for embedded audio, video

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

As seen in new Google Chrome updates, we can see the download button for embedded audio/video in HTML pages. I want to show the same in Firefox & edge browsers. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: you're question is extremely unclear, please edit it.

Comment: thanks bro for your edit

Comment: suggest: add a screenshot of the button for clarity

Comment: This is a chrome development feature, not a web standard implemented.. This is like asking for Windows features in Linux.. Apples and Oranges I'm afraid.. .

Comment: The situation is still the same in 2020. I'd rather stay with the native controls, not developing any custom stuff. And in that case there's a workaround for Firefox (desktop): you can right click on the video and that offers "Save Video As...". I haven't checked on mobile device, hopefully that offers a workaround too.

Answer (score 4):

you can't have the same exact thing unless you create it yourself and disable the download button for Chrome so it'd look consistent in all browsers.

```css
      .download{
height: 45px;
 width: 45px;
 position: relative;
 top: -30px;
 left:-55px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" target="_blank" download><img class="download" src='https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698392-icon-129-cloud-download-128.png'/></a>.
</div>
```

Comment: hope that has been helpful. do let me know if it's not what you're looking for.